# Dynamic image dimension in div

Tags: html, image, css

Need to show the div width in percentage when the image is missing. Since images are loading dynamically I cant fix the image size. All image sizes are mentioned in percentage. So how do we get the div proper width when there is no image loaded.

Here is the demo. 
http://jsfiddle.net/7LfMV/2/

Comment: Are you telling us that the div seems to be appearing very small and you want it appear bigger.

Comment: @Sowmya can you more explain your requirement or any screenshot of your desired result..

Answer (score 0):

Try to change `table-cell` to `inline-block` - http://jsfiddle.net/7LfMV/4/

```
.wraptocenter {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 60% /*Div should take this width*/; 
    background-color:#999
}
```

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/7LfMV/5/

remove `display: table-cell;` and add an `height` to the div

Answer (score 0):

Use `min-height`, `min-width` to set the `height`, `width` when there is no image.

Since you are using display:table-cell I guess you are centering the image inside the div, this will do it.

```
.wraptocenter {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 1px solid red;
    min-height:300px;
    min.width:300px;
}
```

Fiddle Here http://jsfiddle.net/7LfMV/6/